# Stop one cell in a UITableView from being editable

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a UITableView with cells.

The table view shows a list of downloaded video files. If a video file is downloaded I want them to be able to delete it by sliding - ie: delete a row in a table deletes the file. The table view then resets to show "select to download video".

However, non-downloaded files obviously cannot be deleted. How can I turn off the "slide to delete" on THESE PARTICULAR cells?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try: `-[UITableViewDataSource tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:]`
and optionally: `-[UITableViewDelegate tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:]`

;-)